# Probability for intersection of sets

Tags: probability

(It is an easier - hopefully - formulation of a question I asked previously).

Assume that we are given $J$ sets, each set with $n_j$ elements ($J$ and $n_j$ for each $j \le J$ are known). The elements in each set are drawn uniformly from $m$ possible values, without replacement (i.e., the elements in each set are distinct). The sets are independent. $m \ge n_j$.

It is clear that the probability for intersection of size $>$ min$(n_j)$ is $0$. My question is, what is the probability for intersection of **exactly** $i=0,1,2,...,$min$(n_j)$ elements?

I thought that I should write something like $\prod\limits_j {\frac{{{n_j}}}{m}}$ for $i=1$, $\prod\limits_j {\left[ {\left( {\frac{{{n_j}}}{m}} \right)\left( {\frac{{{n_j} - 1}}{{m - 1}}} \right)} \right]}$ for $i=2$ and so on, but I think that it is more complicated.

- Additional question: what happens if it is known that the size of the intersection is at least $l$?

Comment: Maybe you could solve some simpler questions first, e.g., what if $J=2$, and $n_1=n_2=n$?

Comment: I assume you meant $n_1=n_2=m$? In this case the probability is $1$ for $i=m$.

Comment: No, I did not mean $m$. I wrote, and meant, $n_1=n_2$, and let's call that common value $n$. So, two sets, each of size $n$, the $n$ elements being drawn from $m$ available things, $m\ge n$. Can you work out the probabilities in that case? If that case is easy, it might give you (or someone) an idea for doing the general case. If that case is hard, just imagine how hard the general case is!